# Installer script for a modern version of latexmk

Tags: latexmk

(Ubuntu 12.04)

I installed `latexmk` with `sudo apt-get install latexmk` and got version 4.24, which apparently dates back to 2011. It doesn't have some nice features like `-aux-directory` that I'd like.

I tried the latexmk [website](http://users.phys.psu.edu/~collins/software/latexmk-jcc/versions.html), and found newer versions, but none of them seem to have an installer or a deb file. Instead they have an `INSTALL` text file with directions to install. I know how to copy a perl script and a man file, but got lost with step 6: *"Check whether the commands used by latexmk for executing latex etc are correct."*

Is there any modern distribution of `latexmk` that knows how to automatically install itself?

Comment: You really want to use the `latexmk` which is appropriate for the version of TeX you have installed, I think, as newer versions may depend on newer features of TeX stuff. So the best is either to stick to your distro's packages or to install a TeX distribution from upstream, removing your distro's TeX Live from your system. I doubt there's a specific installer for this reason: there's no need and it would be potentially problematic in terms of incompatibilities. It is packaged by distributions of TeX and installed by them. No need to do it manually.